# Conditional recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, conditional-expectation

I have a conditional recurrence relational, that is conditioned on a function value (defined on sequence index).

$
X_{i+1} =
\begin{cases}
    X_{i} + a_1. b^i ,& \text{if } X_i \geq c. b^i\\       
    X_{i} + a_2. b^i,  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

where $a_1, a_2, c, b$ are constants.

I am at large as to how to try to solve the problem. Further, I know that $a_1, a_2$ control the rate of change of $X$ such that it remains close to $c. b^i$.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Determining $X_i$? Or rather showing that choosing the right constants yields some form of control?

Comment: @mvw I know that $a_1 < c$ and $a_2 > c$, therefore $X_i$ would finally converge to $c. b^i$. However I am unable to show that the convergence time, eg. I am unable to show something like $|X_i - c. b^i| < \lambda$ after $i$ steps with high probability. The\ difference is oscillating a lot initially and subsidizes later. I want to have an approximate idea (order) of the convergence time. I don't need any exact answer. I was hoping to model it as recurrence relation and solving for characteristic equation would help me get convergence time ($i$) later.